# What is the difference between "maximally entangled" and "entangled" states?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, textbook-and-exercises, terminology-and-notation

when we talk about bell state we say that these states are **maximally** entangled. so just wanted to understand is there any difference between just **entangled** and **maximally entangled** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maximally entangled state is a state that maximises some entanglement measure.

In the case of bipartite states, this generally means a state that maximises the [entanglement entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement), that is, the von Neumann entropy of the reduced states. Or if you prefer, the Shannon entropy of the vector of eigenvalues of $\operatorname{Tr}_B(\rho)$.

So, for a bipartite two-qubit state, a state $\rho$ is maximally entangled if $\rho_A\equiv\operatorname{Tr}_B(\rho)$ has eigenvalues $(\frac12,\frac12)$. For a *pure* bipartite state $|\psi\rangle$, this is equivalent to asking its Schmidt coefficients to be $(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2})$, meaning that the state must have the form
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt2}(|u_1,v_1\rangle+|u_2,v_2\rangle)$$
for any set of states $|u_i\rangle,|v_i\rangle$ such that $\langle u_1,u_2\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0$.

For multipartite states, things get considerably more complicated, because there isn't a unique "canonical" way to measure entanglement, and thus different states can be "maximally entangled" according to different measures. See *e.g.* ([Plenio, Virmani 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163)) for more detailed discussion on this. Note in particular the discussion in the last paragraph in the second column of page 4 (in the arxiv version), which I'll report here for completeness:

> Now we have a notion of which states are entangled and
> are also able, in some cases, to assert that one state is
> more entangled than another. This naturally raises the
> question whether there is a maximally entangled state,
> i.e. one that is more entangled than all others. Indeed,
> at least in two-party systems consisting of two fixed ddimensional sub-systems (sometimes called qudits), such
> states exist. It turns out that any pure state that is local
> unitarily equivalent to
> $$|\psi_d^+\rangle = \frac{|0,0\rangle+\cdots + |d-1,d-1\rangle}{\sqrt d}$$
> is maximally entangled. This is well justified, because as
> we shall see in the next subsection, any pure or mixed
> state of two d-dimensional systems can be prepared from
> such states with certainty using only LOCC operations.
> We shall later also see that the non-existence of an
> equivalent statement in multi-particle systems is one of
> the reasons for the difficulty in establishing a theory of
> multi-particle entanglement.